# ROS Answers SE migration: roslaunch rqt

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to perform a .launch with rqt?

I can use my puglin with rqt and I use two terminals, one for call rqt and the other to call a .launch. I want to include rqt in my .launch, is it possible?

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="player" output="screen" args="--clock /home/user/bags/bag.bag"/>
    <node pkg="a_package" type="a_node" name="a_node"/>

</launch>
```

I tried this one but it is wrong:

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="rqt" type="rqt" name="rqt"/>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287348/roslaunch-rqt/) by [hecperleo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34460/hecperleo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-03**:
Is this a copy and paste error or does is your opening `launch` tag really a closing one? I.e., change the first `</launch>` to `<launch>`.

**Comment by [hecperleo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34460/hecperleo/) on 2018-04-03**:
Yes, it was a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can do that, you have to call the node `rqt_gui` from the package `rqt_gui` like that :

```
<node name="rqt_gui" pkg="rqt_gui" type="rqt_gui"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3